# How can I change boolean value in objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have such situation:
There is an array:

```
const arr = [
    { 
      id: 0,
      title: 'a',
      status: false
    },
    { 
      id: 1,
      title: 'a',
      status: false
    },
    { 
      id: 2,
      title: 'a',
      status: false
    },
]
```

Then I use this array in my React component to get values, but here I also need to change `status` to true or false in current element (not for all objects)

```
arr.map(el => {
    return (
        <div key={el.id}>
            <div onClick={() => !status}>{div.title}</div> // here
        </div>
    )
})
```

So how can I make this?

Comment: in JS, persisting a value change requires an assignment, which you are not doing: `() => !status` only returns "whatever status is, negated", it doesn't assign that value to anything so there's nowhere to persist it.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans So, could you help me?)

Comment: That depends: did you write this code yourself? If so, you probably already know that the code you're showing doesn't work: `status` isn't even defined in the scope you're showing. What you want is your `onClick` to toggle the current element's `status` boolean, so you that's what you would do: you define a function that can effect `el.status = !el.status`, and then you'd probably want to effect a state update, so you'd probably want `onClick={evt => this.flipElementStatus(el)}` and then make the obvious further changes.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I did like this (answer below) but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about simply (if you have the access to the arr variable) you have an option of getting an index of the array as the 2nd parameter in the map function.

```
arr.map((el, ix) => {
    return (
        <div key={el.id}>
            <div onClick={() => { 
              arr[ix].status = !arr[ix].status
             }}>{div.title}</div> // here
        </div>
    )
})
```

or pull it out in a function (better way) as

```
function handleClick (ix) {
const currentStatus = arr[ix].status
arr[ix].status = !currentStatus
}

arr.map((el, ix) => {
    return (
        <div key={el.id}>
            <div onClick={() => handleClick(ix)}>{div.title}</div> // here
        </div>
    )
})
```

EDIT: Didn't see it was a reactJS, my bad, in that case the best case is to manage it with state.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
const handleClick = (el) => () => {
  el.status = !el.status
}

arr.map(el => {
    return (
        <div key={el.id}>
            <div onClick={handleClick(el)}>{div.title}</div> // here
        </div>
    )
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Maintain array in react state;

```
const [arr,setArr]=useState([
    { 
      id: 0,
      title: 'a',
      status: false
    },
    { 
      id: 1,
      title: 'a',
      status: false
    },
    { 
      id: 2,
      title: 'a',
      status: false
    },
])
```

Write a function to handle the change in state

```
const changeStatus =id=>{
  const newArr = arr.map((el,index)=>{
      if(el.id===id){
         return {...el,status:!el.status}
      }
      else return;
     })
   setArr(newArr)
}
```

call this function on onClick.

```
arr.map(el => {
    return (
        <div key={el.id}>
            <div onClick={() => changeStatus(el.id)}>{div.title}</div> // here
        </div>
    )
})
```